# Zxing Barcode scanner code

Tags: android, barcode, barcode-scanner, zxing

Can anyone explain to me the following code?

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

In the zxing barcode scanner code in Intents.java (like the above). The intent will call which activity and so on?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

You are raising an intent for that specific action (`com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN`).

The barcode scanner application by zxing registers an activity with that action as an intent filter, so Android knows how to resolve intents for that action and links them to that activity.

When you execute that intent, it will open that specific Activity in the zxing application. When this activity finishes it will return control to your Activity with the result. You need to handle this in the [`onActivityResult`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29) callback.

Comment: yes,and how to use the same action in my android app to implement the barcode scanner.what is SCAN in com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN, where exactly it points to?

Comment: Thats simply a string, the link happens in the intent filter declared for the activity that handles barcode scanning. You can take a look at the code here: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/